# Thread stops running when creating an AudioSegment from pydub

Tags: python, multithreading, pydub, audiosegment

I'm creating an application that will play audio on a different thread. The thread runs fine until it reaches the statement where I create an `AudioSegement` from the `pydub` library. I want it to continue executing after this statement so that the audio will play in the background.

```
def add_stream_queue(self):
     search_result = self.search()
     stream = Stream(search_result.get_title(), search_result.get_link())
     self.stream_queue.append_queue(stream)
     if self.first_stream:
         self.stream_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.stream_queue.play_stream_queue, args=[self.play_audio])
         self.stream_thread.start()
```

Here is where I create the thread and it calls the function `play_stream_queue()` which is in the class `StreamQueue`.

```
def play_stream_queue(self, play_audio):
    while self.current_stream < self.get_size():
        self.first_stream = False
        self.manage_stream.download_stream(self.get_stream(self.current_stream).get_link())
        play_audio.start(self.get_stream(self.current_stream).get_title())
        self.current_stream += 1
        print("reached")
    self.first_stream = True
```

In this function I start to play the audio in the line `play_audio.start(...)`. The thread executed perfectly at this point.

```
def start(self, filename):
    self.filename = self.STREAM_FOlDER + filename + ".m4a"
    self.stream_file = AudioSegment.from_file(self.filename, format="m4a")
    print("TEST")
    # Create an interface to PortAudio
    self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    .
    .
    .
```

In the `PlayAudio` class is where the thread is giving me issues. The thread will run fine until it reaches the statement,

```
self.stream_file = AudioSegment.from_file(self.filename, format="m4a")
```

The thread will not continue after this statement.

The odd part is that it used to work perfectly fine and the thread would continue executing after this statement but then it randomly stopped working. I also notice if the program has an error and crashes the `stream_thread` will start playing.